# No Dockerfile matching /home/vscode/azure-pipelines/_work/1/s/**/Dockerfile was found

Tags: yaml, dockerfile, cicd

After installing the docker in the pipeline, it fixed the issue before.
But now it says that there is no dockerfile matching.

I have try different path where the dockerfile is located at but the error has not been solved.

```
      
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName : Login to Docker Hub
    inputs:
        command: login
        containerRegistry: Docker_Hub #fypproject #dockerRegistryServiceConnection1 #

  - task: DockerInstaller@0
    displayName: Docker Installer
    inputs:
        dockerVersion: 17.09.0-ce
        releaseType: stable
    
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: Build and Push
    inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository:   max/newimage # username/contosoRepository for DockerHub
        #$dockerfile: /workspaces/FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
        dockerfile: /workspaces/FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
    #env:
       # PATH: /vscode/bin/linux-x64/695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06/bin/remote-cli:/usr/local/sdkman/bin:/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/java/current/bin:/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/gradle/current/bin:/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/maven/current/bin:/usr/local/sdkman/candidates/ant/current/bin:/usr/local/dotnet/current:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/vscode/.dotnet/tools:/home/vscode/.local/bin
        #PATH: /workspaces/FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
```

[picture of how the repo looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Pwr.png)

Comment: It can't find the `docker` *programme* not the dockerfile *file*.

Comment: thanks i fixed the problem but there is still an issue of no dockerfile to be found

Comment: Saw the updated question. Is the `/workspaces/...` path absolute? Also I noticed that the `dockerfile: /workspaces/...` should be `Dockerfile: /workspaces/...`.

Comment: i try 
```
  Dockerfile: /workspaces/.../FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
```

it have the same error 
but when i try this

```
 Dockerfile: /workspaces/FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
```
this becomes the error
##[error]Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
##[error]The process '/home/vscode/azure-pipelines/_work/_tool/docker-stable/17.9.0-ce/x64/docker' failed with exit code 1

Comment: Okay so your original mistake was a typo. The error you are facing right now is a totally different error unrelated to the original question. Make sure that Docker Engine is up and running. That error's solution varies greatly from system to system, so I can't help you on this question but feel free to check this link; https://linuxhint.com/resolve-docker-daemon-not-running/ and open a new question if there's further issues!

Comment: the docker engine is it something that i have to download. I dont think is in the pipeline yet. 

so i do it like this to install the docker engine

-script:
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin

Comment: Again, I can't give you an exact answer because it varies so much. You should verify that `docker engine` is installed, up and running. I'd start here; https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-fix-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-error/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/docker-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml#syntax), It should be:

```
Dockerfile: /workspaces/FYP_Project/.devcontainer/Dockerfile
```

Notice the uppercase `D`.